# Google Drive API, File export endpoint returns different exported content

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-workspace

So I use the export endpoint

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export
```

And I get different exported content every time I do it.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Have you tried querying the same file in the [try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it) if the output is the same?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the results are the same, but after several clicks you can see the difference